# How to preview Lottie JSON files

Tags: animation, file-format

How can I preview Lottie JSON files after creating them? When I try to view the files, they just open the code in Notepad! :@

I would like to watch the animation like I do after creating a GIF file. Is there any way I can watch a Lottie JSON file like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking to preview a Lottie JSON file created using Adobe After Effects, there are plenty of tools you can use to view them. Some of those tools are listed here on [LottieFiles integrations](https://lottiefiles.com/integrations) page, which can help you view files on Desktop, Mobile and on the web.

Or visit https://lottiefiles.com/preview page, drag & drop your file and you can see your Lottie JSON play, visually.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: To be fair.. there was *no mention* of Lottie files until 3 comment later `:)`

Comment: (face palm) JSON file/format is only for LOTTIE. ( face palm again) @Scott

Comment: No it's not @RussianBlue JSON has **many** uses. Lottie files are just one of them. `:)` No big deal.

Comment: :O I didn't know that. :O am so sorry @Scott

Answer (score 1):

JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) files are not animated images. Or anything like an animated image file. One *can't* simply "watch them". They need a browser, or similar environment, to operate and often exterior objects to manipulate.

JSON files are [strings of code](https://docs.fileformat.com/web/json/) which *contain instructions* for other, exterior, objects (objects which *may* be image files).

Basically a JSON file may tell objects how to move which may result in those objects appearing to be animated. However, that is quite different than an image moving on its own like in the GIF format.

JSON is more closely related to Javascript in nature than to any image format.

---

If you are familiar with animations in Cascading Stylesheets (CSS), the *concept* is similar... the code/markup merely controls *how* elements are animated, but rarely does it create the actual elements.

Comment: So once I render a JSON file I cant watch it like GIF?? There is no way? :'(

Comment: What do you mean by "render"?? Typically, there are other files, such as image files or an HTML file, along *with* any JSON file... .. and the JSON file merely tells the other files how to move/change.

Comment: I created the animation in AE. then created  lottiFiles/JSON files  from that.

Comment: It's web code.. you need a web browser and markup: https://lottiefiles.com/blog/working-with-lottie/how-to-add-lottie-animation-in-web-page-html/

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

i use inari lottie viewer - [Microsoft Store](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/inari-lottie-viewer/9N7FQ9V4CHQS)

Answer (score 0):

I use [LottieFiles](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lottiefiles.vscode-lottie) for [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) (programming code editor) extension.

There is also online tool [Lottie cloud](https://lottie.cloud/app/). Just click borrow then select json file then click on eye icon.